# How to change location of PageController indicator

Tags: iphone, uiview, ios7, uipagecontrol

How do you get the page indicator (dots) to not block the bottom of the screen. I started a basic page based app template, implemented the UIPageDataSource methods to show what page is being displayed. But its blocking the bottom of my screen. If I change the PageControl background to clear its clear but it still takes up the bottom of the screen. No view wants to overlap it. I want the PageControl to be placed anywhere, and a view under it that takes up the whole screen.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you're using a UIPageViewController. Which pr.default includes the UIPageControl element.
If you convert your app into using a regular UIViewController and manually adds the UIPageControl in the .xib(or storyboard) implement the DataSource and Delegate protocols. Then you'll be able to move the UIPageControl anywhere on the scene of your .xib or storyboard (whatever you use).

Basically it's the same thing as when you manually adds a UITableView to an UIViewController instead of using a UITableViewController.